# How to generate Play application default structure using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, playframework, playframework-2.0

I read this [link](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/userguide/play_plugin.html#configuring_play) however I am not sure how to generate the default structure as below?

```
├── app                 → Application source code.
│   ├── assets          → Assets that require compilation.
│   │   └── javascripts → JavaScript source code to be minified.
│   ├── controllers     → Application controller source code.
│   ├── models          → Application business source code.
│   └── views           → Application UI templates.
├── build.gradle        → Your project's build script.
├── conf                → Main application configuration file and routes files.
├── public              → Public assets.
│   ├── images          → Application image files.
│   ├── javascripts     → Typically JavaScript source code.
│   └── stylesheets     → Typically CSS source code.
└── test                → Test source code.
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is. The Gradle plugin follows the default Play Framework organization so you should just be able to follow that layout. What is going wrong? What do you expect?

Comment: I want to create that directory structure such as app, assets, controllers, models, views...I want this structure to be auto generated and yes it is possible with sbt but I am looking to see how to auto generate them using gradle?

Comment: I guess you need to implement a custom task since `play` plugin doesn't come up with such functionality.